# How to acces variable from another class fast?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game on Unity3d I have 2 classes. One of them `ActsGeneral` initialize variable `gameManagerScript` and another `Act_0` try to access it.

Class `GameManager` is stored in object, which exists only on the first scene. I use function `DontDestroyOnLoad()` to use this class on other scenes. So the only way to access variable `gameManagerScript` - is using function `FindGameObjectWithTag`. But when I start the simulation, `Find` don't have enought time to find `gameManagerObject`. And here I have the  error.

[Script Execution Order Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptExecution.html) did not helped too. Should I check if the object equals `null`?

Class **ActsGeneral**

```
void Awake()
{
    gameManagerObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameManager");
    gameManagerScript = gameManagerObject.GetComponent<GameManager>();
}
```

Class **Act_0**

```
void Start()
{
    // error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
    if (actsGeneral.gameManagerScript.currentActNumber == currentLocalActNumber)
    {
    }
}
```

[image]

**Edit1**

I gave `Find` function more time to find the object `gameManagerObject`, but now I still have error. All objects and component are enabled and I set up **Script Execution Order Settings**. But it still don't work. I just don't understand the reason of that.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine("StartDelay");
}

IEnumerator StartDelay()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
    if (actsGeneral.gameManagerScript != null)
        if (actsGeneral.gameManagerScript.currentActNumber == currentLocalActNumber)
        {
            Debug.Log("222");
        }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: if you want fast and dirty, use singleton pattern at your own risk!

Comment: @Bijan I don't want dirty. Maybe I shoult use a coroutine to give `Find` some time to find the object. Just want to know, what other options is possible

Comment: Have you tried to add a `Debug.Log( gameManagerScript )` in the ActsGeneral script and a `Debug.Log( actsGeneral.gameManagerScript)` in the Act_0 script ?

Comment: @Hellium First `Debug.Log(actsGeneral.gameManagerScript)` give null reference exception error, then `Debug.Log(gameManagerScript)` say, the the object is exists

Comment: @dima : Then, you have a problem of execution order. Does the ActsGeneral script and the object holding it are enabled in the scene before you hit "play" ?

Comment: @Hellium answered in the Edit1

Comment: figure out what is null and why. use Debug.Log for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way when you try to access data from another class in a different scene is using singleton pattern.

First add this script to your proyect:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Singleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static T instance;

    /**
      Returns the instance of this singleton.
   */
    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = (T)FindObjectOfType(typeof(T));

                if (instance == null)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("An instance of " + typeof(T) +
                                   " is needed in the scene, but there is none.");
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Second add this to your **ActsGeneral** class.

```
    using UnityEngine;

    public class ActsGeneral : Singleton<ActsGeneral> {
    ...
```

And in your class **Act_0** from the other scene

```
public class Act_0 : MonoBehaviour {

ActsGeneral ac;

..
void Start()
{
    ac = ActsGeneral.Instance;

    //Do something with ac ....
}
```

Remember that the GameObject with the ActsGeneral script must have a don't destroy on load property and must be in the first scene loaded.

---

If this doesn't work, the problem is in the Awake event of your **ActsGeneral** script, so you can change it for this:

```
void Awake()
}
    gameManagerScript = GameManager.Instance;
}
```

And in the **GameManager** script

```
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : Singleton<GameManager> {
...
```